phpmyadmin app is unable to connect to mysql in minkube when attaching a persistent volume to mysql data
I have created a 2 node cluster in minikube which should connect phpmyadmin app to mysql database in the pod. My app connects to the mysql database when the permanent volume is not attached through permanent volume claim. Below Manifest showing this situation!
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None

# ---
# apiVersion: v1
# kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
# metadata:
#   name: mysql-pvc
#   namespace: default
# spec:
#   accessModes:
#   - ReadWriteOnce
#   resources:
#     requests:
#       storage: 1Gi

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: default
spec:
  # serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-mysql
        image: mysql:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: mydb
        # - name: MYSQL_USER
        #   value: khurram
        # - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        #   value: khurram123
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          # valueFrom:
          #   secretKeyRef:
          #     name: postgres-secret
          #     key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: my-secret-pw
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu:    "700m"
          requests:
            memory: "200Mi"
            cpu:    "100m"

      #   volumeMounts:
      #   - name: my-sql-volume
      #     mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      
      # volumes:
      # - name: my-sql-volume
      #   persistentVolumeClaim:
      #     claimName: mysql-pvc

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myphpadmin
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: myphpadmin

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myphpadmin
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myphpadmin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myphpadmin
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-myphpadmin
        image: phpmyadmin
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: PMA_HOST
          value: mysql
        # - name: PMA_USER
        #   value: root
        # - name: PMA_PORT
        #   value: "3306"
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: my-secret-pw
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu:    "700m"
          requests:
            memory: "200Mi"
            cpu:    "100m"



but as soon as i add permanent volume through pvc, my phpmyadmin app does not connect to mysql database and gives me an error as attached.enter image description here
Please support in resolving the issue.......
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: default
spec:
  # serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-mysql
        image: mysql:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: mydb
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: my-secret-pw
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu:    "700m"
          requests:
            memory: "200Mi"
            cpu:    "100m"

        volumeMounts:
        - name: my-sql-volume
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      
      volumes:
      - name: my-sql-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pvc

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myphpadmin
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: myphpadmin

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myphpadmin
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myphpadmin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myphpadmin
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-myphpadmin
        image: phpmyadmin
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: PMA_HOST
          value: mysql
        # - name: PMA_USER
        #   value: root
        # - name: PMA_PORT
        #   value: "3306"
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: my-secret-pw
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu:    "700m"
          requests:
            memory: "200Mi"
            cpu:    "100m"

I did everything i can do to resolve the issue but all in vain!
